# Is it bad to use a blender with protein powder

Tags: workout, protein, protein-shakes

Is it true that using a blender with protein powder, like whey, is bad because the blender can break up the amino acids?  This sounds crazy to me, but I've heard it more than once, so I thought I'd ask.

---

The best I could find was [this forum](http://www.elitefitness.com/forum/diet-bodybuilding/mixing-protein-shakes-blender-155924.html).  This post

> Mechanical agitation will have no effect on the chemical bonds of the protein. It's like saying that a blender will break up water into hydrogen and oxygen. Last time I checked that didn't happen.
>
> As long as you don't throw the shake into the microwave you are fine

seemed compelling, but it didn't exactly cite anything to back it up.

Comment: The burden of proof is on the claim that the blender *will* have detrimental effects, no?

Comment: @Dave - well, in a sense, from a Skeptics point of view, yeah: claims like this need to be supported by evidence to be taken seriously.  For me though, I just want to make sure I'm not hurting my protein powder by blending it, so I was wondering if anyone here had any info.

Comment: If it does I would be in trouble, I always mix my protein shakes in a blender.

Comment: @Dave: No. I do not like either way around, but it's closer to scientific method to say that the burden of proof is on the claim that blended-protein has a nutritional benefit.

Comment: I think this might actually be a better fit for Skeptics.SE, since this question isn't really related to fitness, but simply proving or disproving a nutrition claim. Plus, they have specific standards for evidence that would do this discussion well.

Comment: I always throw a banana, protein powder, a raw egg and milk in a blender and just mix it all together. I've heard a couple of times that blending protein powder could be bad. I sure hope not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mechanical agitation can denature proteins, so that the proteins will no longer function correctly in their original state.

But, it's likely the proteins are already denatured as a consequence of manufacturing. And, your digestive system will break down the proteins into amino acids anyway, in order to rebuild them into new proteins.

Mechanical agitation (by a blender) cannot break up amino acid components, which are molecular.

Therefore, I cannot imagine that blending the protein will make any difference to the nutritional value.

Comment: This. You can only denature a protein down to its primary state, and the body will do this anyway, as it doesn't use protein, it uses amino acids derived from proteins. So if the blender does denature the protein at all, it's basically making digestion easier.

Answer (score 0):

It won't hurt the protein powder. Many people use a shaker or a blender. Blender is popular when mixing with fruit to make a smoothie type of product.

Comment: If you are going to vite down an answer, should add a comment as to why to help others in the future provide meaningful answers.

Comment: I agree, Wayne, so I upvoted to counter the bozo.

Answer (score -6):

Amino acids can be denatured because of heat..and heat is produced from the movement of the blades of the blender..so yes theoretically amino acids can be denatured this way

Comment: The blender is not a closed system, so ... nope

Comment: Also see other comments/answers. Denaturing the protein does nothing but make it slightly easier to digest. It doesn't do anything to the amino acids which is the important part.