# Can I freeze a pre-mixxed protein-powder solution as ice-cubes?

Tags: nutrition, protein, protein-shakes

## Preamble: My situation

I do bodyweight exercise once a day and take lots of Protein in order to optimize MPS, mostly following the recommendations from [jorn trommelen](https://www.nutritiontactics.com/measure-muscle-protein-synthesis/).

I prepare my shakes in a Vitamix, [0.6L container](https://www.vitamix-deutschland.de/Vitamix-ASCENT-06-L-Mix-Go-Behaelter) (As pointed out in [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6167/is-it-bad-to-use-a-blender-with-protein-powder), there shouldn't be a problem with that.)
In order to optimize my routine, I want to minimize the time I need to prepare pre- and post workout shakes.
A shake typically consists of

- a few ice cubes
- about 4 frozen strawberries
- 40g protein powder (I use a scoop to get the right amount)
- water

Handling the protein powder itsself can be a bit annoying:

- protein powder will stick to the walls of the container, increasing the effort necessary to clean it afterwards.
- protein powder might spill in the kitchen, spill on top of the container, increasing the effort to clean even more

## The Idea

The idea is to

1. pre-mix the protein powder
2. pour the mixture into 125ml silicon ice-cube-tray (=> 40g powder per cube)
3. freeze it and use the frozen cubes in the vitamix

## My questions

- How many cubes would it make sense to pre-make based on:

  - How long should I expect the pre-mixxed protein ice-cubes to last?
  - Can I expect the protein to degrade in the freezer over time?
- Is there any other reason that this is a bad idea (mostly with respect to MPS)? Does anyone do this or have experience with it?

Comment: This is more of a shelf life type question than a fitness question. May be better answered on https://cooking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @E.Aigle you're right it's about shelf life - but protein powder really is very specific to fitness - I would expect rather the fitness community to be interested in this and also be knowledgable, than the cooking-community. also it contains the question about why it might be a bad idea with respect to MPS which has nothing to do with cooking

Comment: You aren't asking about fitness though, you're asking about meal prep / shelf life. Your question will probably be closed for being off topic here.

Comment: When I search for questions with repsect to handling protein powder I do find more unclosed helpful questions here (i.e. "can i blend it", "can i use it together with ice") than on cooking.stackexchange.
Also, a supplement is really not a meal, and I'm not sure food prep is a good term for it...

Comment: Thanks anyways - I suppose I will wait a bit. if more people or mods think it's better on cooking, I will move it there.

Comment: You may be able to find a recipe for these if you search for "Proteinsicles" or "Protein Popsicles". Your version will work though. They can last weeks but they get freezer burn just like anything in the freezer so you have to put them in a container or cover them. It doesn't affect MPS.